# Should questions that are "on hold" "closed" still accept down votes?

Tags: discussion

Shouldn't it be more like, if a question gets "closed" or put "on hold" be temporarily frozen (from up votes / down votes ) till the question gets reopened?

*Why is it currently the other way around?*

The way I see it is, when a question gets "closed" or put "on hold" the *OP* understands there is something clearly wrong with his question.

Continuous down votes discourages the OP from actually trying to make it better and seeing that most questions ( *totally a guess, please tell me if I'm wrong* ) that get "closed" or put "on hold" come from new users, I don't think they feel very welcomed?

Comment: This affects the whole network, so should probably be on http://meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Should I delete this question and go post it on meta.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @Grimbode No; and there's nothing wrong with it staying here either.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker would it not be better for this to be on MetaSE? I doubt it would be changed just for SO.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Without pulling up Shog9's exact words, there's nothing wrong with something being discussed on a local meta site and elevated to MetaSE; or it being discussed in both places.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker ah OK; duly noted, thanks.

Comment: Voting is a **different** signal from putting something on hold. The two aspects are orthogonal, and should not be seen as connected.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't quite agree. They are already connected. How many questions that get closed or put on hold actually reopen? Why? I think it's simply because the down votes discourage them from trying to make their question better.

Comment: How is this off-topic?

Comment: @Grimbode It's not.

Comment: @GrantWinney I was thinking something on the same line. Would it be hard to implement such a thing? I like the idea on giving the OP time to modify his original question. To better it. Instead of trying to better it and watching down vote after down vote occur. Really discouraging.

Comment: @GrantWinney getting a question to -3 allows a 20k user to cast speedy delete votes on it for situations where its really bad. I've often done this on other sites. If there was a lock, it would mean an awful question (there was a really creepy one about someone wanting to design an AI girlfriend) was sitting on our front page for an hour. At -4 it doesn't show up on the front page (though still in /questions). These pile on votes can be needed to help maintain the quality of the site and prevent nasty comments and drama in questions.

Comment: @MichaelT don't questions that are "on hold" or "closed" get removed from the front page? Maybe have a cap of downvotes at -3 for an hour? Give the user time to better his question.

Comment: @Grimbode Nope. On hold and closed can still be on the front page. This happens when they are bumped with an edit (and you want eyeballs on them then). SO moves faster so new 'on hold' questions are frequently off the bottom before 5th close vote is cast. Other sites are a bit slower and on hold questions can sit on the front page for some time. Why cap it? Every vote counts and is independent of others. I'd hate to have to wait an hour (or for someone to come by with a sympathy upvote).

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Down votes feed a number of systems, including the Roomba scripts which delete questions with various conditions.

If there was no down voting on closed questions, in effect every closed question would be historically locked and prevented from automatic removal. This would be *very* bad because there is a lot of cruft that is still lurking out there - closed, sitting with an upvote until someone comes along sees that it isn't a useful question and down votes it.

If I was to come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351667/stack-overflow-exceptions-in-linux):

> [image: old closed question]

why shouldn't I be able to down vote it?

Comment: From this point of view, that does make a lot of sense. I just feel that a lot of users don't even bother trying to understand. The moment they see something put "on hold" or "closed" they just down vote without even looking further. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Grimbode the concepts are orthogonal to each other. A down vote is for "no research, unclear, not useful". Many closed questions fall into those categories, but not all. A lot of users also fire off a question, get an answer, and then never come back to it - no matter what (up votes, down votes, closed or open).

Comment: did you notice Grant's comment?