# Why don't we lock voting on closed questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, downvotes, closed-questions

This issue came to mind since I'm facing the same in my only question; posted a long time ago. Although the question has been closed with the appropriate reasons.

But *I didn't edit it further because the answer I got solved my problem*.  Hence, I understand that editing in references or additional information to clarify the question is not required.

However, I've noticed that despite the question being closed, other users have kept voting it down, which has caused me to lose reputation.

This could have been averted if there was a feature which locked **closed questions** so that *no one could vote (down or up or accept answer) on it*.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290187/should-questions-that-are-on-hold-closed-still-accept-down-votes

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313214/is-it-reasonable-that-a-question-can-still-be-voted-on-after-its-been-closed

Comment: slightly related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303808/getting-down-votes-to-an-closed-question-after-one-years

Comment: Just an FYI:  normal people can vote to close a question too.  Not just diamond moderators.

Comment: "I never intend to fix my question" is the worst argument you could have given for this feature request.

Comment: @BSMP:  But it's the most common.  It's less than ideal - I don't disagree there - but that doesn't mean that it's necessarily *wrong*.

Comment: @Makoto But it does mean that they should be prepared for the consequences of that decision.  They've chosen to take a course of action that's not helpful, they're going to get feedback on the post accordingly.

Comment: @Servy:  That comment was really meant for us, honestly.  I get that this is the ideal thing to do and that there are Consequences™ if a user chooses to not come back to edit their question, but it's important that we not blow a capillary every time that happens since it happens *all* the time.

Comment: *but that doesn't mean that it's necessarily wrong* @Makoto The feature request or their reasoning for it? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @BSMP:  The reasoning.  It's not surprising to me to see that users are only interested in Stack Overflow to get their question answered and nothing further.

Comment: @Makoto exactly why bashing unnecessarily on question or OP when solution is already there and acceptance had been given ?

Comment: @Skynet:  Just because it's a fact of life doesn't mean we're going to be *happy* about it...

Comment: @Skynet RE: "robbing": People that cast a downvote do not earn that reputation, nobody is stealing anything. Also, there is no reason to believe that the people talking with you here downvoted your question. "You guys" (that downvoted) are not necessarily the people helping you here.

Comment: In any event, my real question is rather: why would we *actually* prevent votes on closed question. So far, your only argument is "I lost 6 reputation". I don't understand what the problem is. This was a somewhat poorly researched question, it got downvoted, somewhat rightfully. I mean, the documentation you link to is not even talking about sub queries!

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier check the question post date, 3 years earlier it didn't have that much resources to back my researches. If it did I wouldn't have posted in SO to insult myself that I didn't researched on it. These kind of new frameworks need replies from persons those working on it. Fresh heads likes of us couldn't find it with nominal knowledge of the framework. Although this community is for help rather this community became place to brag nothing else.

Comment: Compare my question with this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047149/subquery-in-codeigniter-active-record which one is more poorly documented but mine got down-voted rigorously due to some Mods thought lets close it down. But our question are 90% similar of it's kind. Really I want to know what kind of value it adds to network by abusing ones privileges of being moderator.

Comment: And more importantly mostly those who sneak out such question and down-vote it to show their privilege doesn't care for answers cause they're well aware that down-voting on an answer will similarly cause backlash in an sense of rep loss to down-voter as well. However in case of question they doesn't lose any reps.

Comment: @Skynet it's not "mods", who decided to close the question, but normal users, like you and me. Nobody is "sneaking" out on your answer. I repeat, you lost 6, no, 4 since you also accepted an answer, you lost *four* reputation! How can you accuse everyone of being jerks over that?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier let me know then how come a 3 years old question suddenly got so bad in test that they given back to back 6 down-votes on it. Wherever it's having accepted answer and the information followed by suggestion given by mods in closed question alert.

Comment: @Skynet I thought it's weird that your question got downvoted since Nov 3. But after finding out that you linked your own post on [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/376195/2821954), I didn't find it surprising. You just invoked [meta effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect)... and also I think you're confusing between real mods (with a diamond after their usernames) and high-rep users using their privileges...

Comment: @AndrewT. exactly my point, I had to instigate these people in order they took turns to check the question whether it's should be in SO or not then due it's closed it's down-voted. Kind of illogical such they couldn't find it unless I linked it to them, so it was fine till they can see it ? Or I've just provoked them to use or better to say abuse their privileges upon that question.

Comment: @Skynet well, apparently your question is unpopular; only 315 views in 3 years. And your question was already in negative (+4-7=-3) before meta effect. While it might be suck to get negative meta effect, I don't see any abuse though... (users are free to vote anytime, unless the post is locked for some reasons)

Comment: @Skynet hmmm no. You basically went in front of one of the most critical subset of users of this site, then pointed them to your question. How is it abuse to vote on content? The 'meta effect' is a double edged sword: it brings more visibility to a question. So good Qs get massive upvotes... And Q's that don't meet the quality standards end up having a bunch of downvotes. It's not abuse... It's just a bit more attention to your question...

Answer (score 18):

> But I didn't edit it further because the answer I got solved my problem. Hence, I understand that editing in references or additional information to clarify the question is not required.

It might not be required for you.  It's required for us to ensure that your question is useful.  If your question is unclear, lacking a reproducible example, not accurately describing the problem, or whatever, then it inhibits others with that problem from finding your question, determining that it's about their problem, and then getting their solution.

So we *want* you to edit your question and fix it, even if you don't want an answer anymore.  Thus you have an incentive to fix your question (in the form of votes).  After all, closure is not designed to be permanent.  It's designed to be a state where you fix your question up so that it can be reopened.

Comment: Consider to add that closing of a question does not make it non-searchable via search engines (unlike deletion).

Comment: @Servy when I've a solution to my problem then what's possible additional information one can provide. Isn't it very much unnecessary to do so?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov my question was poorly written and it was edited added necessary information however it didn't stopped SO mods to close it down. But you may point out if they were right I still need to provide more information on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25042018/how-to-write-a-sub-query-in-codeigniter

Comment: @Skynet You don't state what you want to do, you don't state why it doesn't work, you've just posted some code and said, "It doesn't work".  There is no question; there is no problem, there is no statement of what a correct solution would do.  What makes you think it's a good question or that no other information could be useful for it?

Comment: @Servy that sub-query itself is self-explanatory, why it doesn't worked that I wanted to know but more than that I needed a solution which I've got.

Comment: @Skynet No, i'ts not.  It's important for you to *explicitly* state why it doesn't work, not to just post some code that doesn't work and expect everyone else to figure out what's wrong with it.

Comment: @Servy not everyone is expert in particular technology for me I was not fluent enough in CI, hence I worked upon SQL and provided same in order to seek a solution.

Comment: @Skynet You don't need to be an expert in a technology to explain what your problem was.  You didn't even *try*.

Answer (score 14):

Because that would give any user with a gold badge the power to single-handedly lock the votes on a question.
That's not a good thing.

It would also prevent upvotes on questions that were actually good, but no-one ever complains about getting upvoted, any way.

Answer (score 4):

If we locked voting on closed questions, how would you get feedback as a question asker that your edits have improved things or not?

If your downvoted question starts to attract upvotes or at the very least cancellation of prior downvotes then you know you're now on the right track and might hope your question would be reopened.

If you don't care that your question is clear enough or that it's reopened, that's up to you but we care that questions are helpful to everyone.

If you're invested enough to take the time to write this Meta question then why not actually fix the problem and clarify your original question so it no longer attracts downvotes. In that sense voting is having the desired effect, i.e. it's stung you into action, you just now need to take the right action to fix things.